# Fake Call using PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have a client that would like me to build them a "Phoney Phone Call" program on the iPhone. 
I need the ability to fake a phone call and have the call come from someone in the contacts and the ability to choose the ring tone.

Is this possible using PhoneGap? Anyone have any info on this?
Thanks!
Mike

Comment: I can assure you one thing. Your client will not be happy to know that you are sharing his project idea with everybody here. Those information should be kept private.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is not possible. Haven't used PhoneGap but don't believe PhoneGap gives access to the Address Book APIs. So the "have the call come from someone in contacts" is not possible. The other stuff should be.

FYI, fake call apps do already exist. It might be wise to notify your client of this.